# Is it possible to run a Nightwatch test by partial name?

Tags: node.js, testing, nightwatch.js, ui-testing

```
"test:automation-by-name": "node ./nightwatch.js  -e local --suiteRetries 1 \
 --reporter ./client/tests/automation/html-reporter.js --test client/tests/automation/test/cards.js \
 --testcase 'Card Order.*'",
```

The issue here is that the test name is 136 characters, so it's a lot easier (and less error-prone) to regex it. But when I try the above I get:

```
Error: "Card Order.*" is not a valid testcase in the current test suite.
```

But I do have tests that match that name:

```
$ cat client/tests/automation/test/cards.js | grep 'Card Order'

'Card Order and Content is Correct - [redacted super long name]': function (client, done) { 
'Card Order, Content is Correct [redacted]': function (
'Card Order and Content is Correct - [redacted]': function (client, done) {
'Card Order and Content is Correct - [redacted]': function (client, done) {
'Card Order and Content is Correct - [redacted]': function (
```

Is there a way to use wildcards with this `testcase` arg? The [docs](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/running-tests/command-line-options.html) don't discuss it.

Comment: I suggest trying to use tags in your tests to avoid lengthy test names.

Comment: Tried that. I added a tag to the test I wanted to run but it wouldn't run just that tag because the outer scope had tags too. Had to specify all three tags to get it to run, which defeated the purpose.

Comment: Weird, I use more than one tags on my tests. One represents the outer scope and one the test it self.